# Add an additional 160px before adding/removing class?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add an additional 160px before adding & removing class.

Original working jQuery:

```
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  let elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  let elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
  let viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  let viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($('#main-header').isInViewport()) {
    $('#main-menu').removeClass('hide');
  } else {
    $('#main-menu').addClass('hide');
  }
});
```

My attempt:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($('#main-header').isInViewport() + 160) {
    $('#main-menu').removeClass('hide');
  } else {
    $('#main-menu').addClass('hide');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try extending jQuery:

```
// own custom jQuery function
$.fn.isInViewportWithMargin = function(px) {
  let elementTop = $(this).offset().top - px;
  let elementBottom = elementTop + ( $(this).outerHeight() + px*2 );
  let viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  let viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($('#main-header').isInViewportWithMargin(160)) {
    $('#main-menu').removeClass('hide');
  } else {
    $('#main-menu').addClass('hide');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks you for this.